# Ionic error installation with node on windows 7 64 bit

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm, installation

What's means this errors ? please !

npm ERR! node v4.5.0 
npm ERR! npm v3.10.9
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\abbrev d6cf8733
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename

Comment: I had the same problem, In my case, the problem went away with a complete removal of node_modules/ (rm -rf-style).